# Optimize MS Sync Framework

Tags: optimization, microsoft-sync-framework

Good day! Sorry for my bad english.

I want to ask about MS Sync Framework 2.1. I have software for WM 6.0, that sync with SQL Server 2008 by SyncFramework use WCF, and i have a problem with speed of sync. I have 38 dictioanary tables and 10-15 data tables, each of tables doesn't have records more than 200, and time of this process is 6-8 minute only for dowload.

Can somebody tell me, how i can optimize for faster work my sync soft? Eny ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: [Synchronization Services for ADO .NET for Devices: Improving performance by skipping tables that don’t need synchronization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/synchronization-services-for-ado-net-for-devices-improving-performance-by-skipping-tables-that-don-t-need-synchronization.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, for topic. But in my app, i have it, i have functionality that filter tables, that don't needed. I talk about first time download.

Comment: are you creating the client tables on first download as well? maybe a good amount of time is actually spent creating the client schema than actually downloading data.

Comment: No, table already exist. I thing there is many operation hapens when i call sync method, that don't need, because of what i have big time sync.